# подскажите по each

Tags: groovy

Коллеги подскажите джуну, есть вот такая таблица https://pastebin.com/X5myyTS6,
задача получить всех юзеров которые есть в конкретной ячейке каждой строки.
Написал вот такой скрипт https://pastebin.com/iWJJvqrD, за запуске , получаю ошибку 
"Cannot invoke method select() on null object"
То есть он не смог разобрать ячейку во второй строке,
Если в этой ячейке нет ничего, то все работает без ошибок, так же ,если в 11 строке убрать [e], ошибки нет, но тогда скрипт отрабатывает неверно. 
Подскажите в чем моя ошибка и как исправить.

Comment: Я рекомендую выложить конкретные строчки куда, в которых вы не можете разобраться.

Comment: спасибо всем. уже разобрался.